# define a sting as a date and add days

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a string that represent a date (ex. 01/10/2022 d/m/Y) and I want to add 90 days to this date, the problem I think I have is that php dont know how do add the 90 days to this date because is a string. I tried different solution posted by others but without a good result.

One example that I tried is:

```
$nextduedate = "01/10/2022";
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $nextduedate);
$myDateTime = $myDateTime->format('d/m/Y');
$number_of_days = 90;
$str =' + '. $number_of_days. ' days';
$myDateTime = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($myDateTime. $str));
echo $myDateTime;
```

adn the result is 10/04/2022 istead of 01/01/2023

I know im missing something but I dont know what.

Comment: When you use strtotime with a date format like 01/10/2022 it will be interpreted like m/d/Y and not like your "special format" "d/m/Y".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **Date Object**, this script can help you.
You have to use **"modify" function**

```
<?
$startEntry = "01/10/2022";
$nbDays     = 90;


$stringDiff = "+".$nbDays." days";

$startDate  = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $startEntry);
$endDate    = $startDate->modify($stringDiff);

echo $endDate->format('d/m/Y');
?>
```